# Can't get Logs to Show Real IP w/ mod_remoteip and Sucuri

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, centos7

Really hope someone can help. I'm trying to the use the Sucuri CloudProxy reverse proxy on my new site.

To try and get the real IP I've installed mod_remoteip.so and it's loaded in my HTTPD config file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf):

```
LoadModule remoteip_module    /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_remoteip.so
```

I've also created */etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_remoteip.conf* and in there I've added:

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
RemoteIPHeader HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP
RemoteIPHeader HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
RemoteIPHeader HTTP_X_REAL_IP
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2a02:fe80::/29
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 192.88.134.0/23
```

Per their instructions here: https://kb.sucuri.net/cloudproxy/Troubleshooting/same-user-ip

I'm running Apache 2.4.6

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
```

I'm also on CentOS 7:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

I've restarted apache multiple times, even tried rebooting, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the real IP to show up in the logs.

I am using the right log format I believe:

```
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

I replaced %h with %a because I was reading on some troubleshooting pages that it had helped, but in my case it didn't. This was the site I was referencing: https://trick77.com/apache2-2-4-logging-remote-ip-address-using-mod_remoteip/

I'm reached the end of my wits.. :(.. any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: the syntax looks correct and should work as long as the header is correct, and the config is enabled e.g. with `a2enconf remoteip.conf` (in a similar manner to the [cloudflare setup](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/restoring-visitor-ips/restoring-original-visitor-ips)); and slightly unrelated — it might make sense to include both the `%h` _and_ `%a` so that you get to see both IP's in your log, although it might trip log parsers if you use any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your "RemoteIPHeader" is not configured properly. Remove what you have there and try to set it only as:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

And it should work. Hope it helps.

thanks,

Comment: You are correct! Thank you so much.. that did the trick.. I see what you mean, I removed the three RemoteIPHeaders and it worked by leaving **X-Forwarded-For**